# how to use a median user defined function on dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def func_median(n_num):
    
    #n_num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    n = len(n_num)
    
    n_num.sort() 
    if n % 2 == 0:
        median1 = n_num[n//2]
        median2 = n_num[n//2 - 1]
        median = (median1 + median2)/2
    else:
        median = n_num[n//2]
    print("Median is: " + str(median))
func_median([10.0,20.0,30.5,40.0])
Median is: 25.25 #working fine
```

when applying it on a data set its throwing an error

```
new_df_housing['median_income']=new_df_housing['median_income'].apply(func_median)
```

**error - TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()**

dataset -

[image: 1]

Comment: can you provide a sample from your data set ? it will help to know how this data look like.

Comment: Unsure what group you want to take the median over. Over all houses with the same latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0):

I am assmuming you are using pandas and there is an easier way to get a median of a specific column.
try:

```
median_income = df['median_income'].median()
print(median_income)
```

Let me know if it works and hope it helps!